# How to add routing to sub folders in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to break my routes.js file into separate files so it's easier to work with.

Here is my folder structure

```
routes.js
views/
├─ 1537/
│  ├─ prototype-4/
│  │  ├─ _routes.js
│  │  ├─ report.html
```

**routes.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.use('/1537/prototype-4', require('./views/1537/prototype-4/_routes'));

module.exports = router
```

**views/1537/prototype-4/_routes.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/report/:reportId', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Hello world");
    res.render("report");
});

module.exports = router
```

When I run the following it returns 'hello world' but it can't find the template.

> template not found: report.html

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to use nodejs' `__dirname` to resolve the path in **views/1537/prototype-4/_routes.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/report/:reportId', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Hello world");
    res.render(__dirname + "/report");
});

module.exports = router
```